# Slow loading times for WMS layer

Tags: wms, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am using a the Themed overlays found at https://apps.nationalmap.gov/services/. Particularly the "3DEPElevation:Hillshade Elevation Tinted" layer. I have loaded this successfully into my WPF application that is using ArcGis runtime for .net. The image loads fine but it takes quite a long time for a new image to load when I zoom or pan. Is there a way I can store the WMS layer locally or really anything to increase the loading times of new tiles ? I also experience the same thing in QGIS. Really long load times. I am new to GIS so I am still learning the concepts but I cant imagine this is my internet slowing things down as the baselayer I have loaded loads very quickly.

Any tips?

Comment: Layers works pretty fast for me in QGIS, a couple of seconds perhaps for a request like: `https://elevation.nationalmap.gov:443/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=20.60784320165051398,-95.58141927726671838,52.84265673075481118,-71.95642045851673174&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=568&HEIGHT=775&LAYERS=3DEPElevation%3AHillshade Elevation Tinted&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE` (URL captured using the QGIS debugging tools)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd ideally want to use that WMS layer as a basemap but with the load times compared to my current basemap it is a huge time difference.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the nuance of you wanting to run the WMS layer as a base map in response to my comment. why is loading the layer in QGIS and zooming around not like a a base map?

Comment: If the response is too slow you might consider using their WCS and downloading all the data, then serving it back locally, or perhaps you could cascade the service through your own WMS/WMTS and set up some caching